# Python XOR operation and ser.read()

Tags: python, xor, xbee

I am implementing a Python script to read frames sent by a XBee. PC will receive frames and process them.

I have a problem because I use AP=2 in XBee, so all frames can have escaped characters. I want to detect them and put the real values before operating with them.

This is a fragment of code in which I read a escaped byte:

```
read = ser.read()
if(toHex(read) != '7d'): #toHex converts a byte in Hex representation
    #escaped char
    read = logical_xor(ser.read(), 20) #you have to take the next character and make xor
#################################
def logical_xor(str1, str2):
    return bool(str1) ^ bool(str2)
```

But it tells me that str cannot be used in that operation. Do you know what I have to do to solve it?

Also, I used to read four bytes together like this:

```
read = ser.read(4)
```

... and try to to the same as before (try to get the next position (`read[x+1]`)) but it tells me similar things...

Conversion consists in making `XOR` to next char and `0x20`.

Any idea?

Comment: `20 != 0x20`, `bool(str1) == (str == "")`. I don't see what you expect to happen here.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `toHex`?

Comment: Why not configure the XBee with `AP=1` so you don't have to deal with escaped characters?  I've never been a fan of escaped mode, it just makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be overcomplicating things - what exactly does `ser.read()` return? A single character string? If so:

```
read = ser.read()
if ord(read) != 0x7d:
    #escaped char
    read = ord(ser.read()) ^ 0x20
```

Comment: I convert ser.read() using toHex to get a representative value because I can't use value read because it prints rubbish. If I use read[x] = ord(read[x+1])^0x20. It tells me "'str' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: @user1298272: In python, this is invalid: `x = "ab"` `x[0] = "c"`. Strings are immutable.